# Is there a way to find the maximum character limit for a parameter I need to pass in a webservice?

Tags: xml, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to compile a guide for a webservice API. One information that would be useful would be to know that character limit for each value that can be passed in the webservice. I would like to find a quick and easy way to get this information.

I have tried looking at the SQL DB it is writing to but the character limits on the DB table do not correspond with the limits on the WebService.

At the moment my only way of trying to find this is by entering incrementally longer values until I receive the character limit. I would love to know if there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: Does this webservice have some kind of descriptor? Your question is tagged with [tag:wsdl]; if you pull that down, the information could be in there.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to know the language, framework (and possibly language version) of the webservice

Once you find that, you can check the documentation/google for the maximum allowed parameter limit for that language (and language version)

For instance the maximum length of a string in Java is 2,147,483,647 characters